# Unable to convert Javascript code to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Like some of the beginners, i have been trying to learn JQuery by transforming the javascript code to jquery.
Now here is a part of code which use HTML Canvas and allows user to draw and delete the content in Canvas using Jquery:

```
function init() {
canvas = $('#can');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
w = canvas.width;
h = canvas.height;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    findxy('move', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    findxy('down', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    findxy('up', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    findxy('out', e)
}, false);}
```

This code was initially in Javascript, i have just changed the Selectors to use it as Jquery. But I am getting the error as in the 3rd line of this code as:
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Could you please guide why i am getting this. Thanks

Comment: You are use DOM element function on a jQuery object. That isn't a good situation to convert Javascript to jQuery...

Comment: Why not convert the rest as well -> http://jsfiddle.net/5uazu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getContext` is not a jQuery property, therefore you need to access the underlying DOM element and call it on that:

```
ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
```

Also, jQuery convention is to use the `$` prefix on a variable containing a jQuery object. `width` and `height` are also methods, so should have trailing brackets. Finally, if you want to use jQuery, use it to attach your events too:

```
function init() {
    var $canvas = $('#can');
    var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    var w = $canvas.width();
    var h = $canvas.height();

    $canvas
        .on("mousemove", function(e) { findxy('move', e); })
        .on("mousedown", function(e) { findxy('down', e); })
        .on("mouseup", function(e) { findxy('up', e); })
        .on("mouseout", function(e) { findxy('out', e); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This way it worked. Also can you tell me if there is anything wrong with below, its not working somehow:
function erase() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    $('#canvasimg').style.display = "none";
}

Comment: `ctx` is declared inside your `init()` function, so would not be accessible from `erase()`. You either need to create `ctx` in that function too, or make it available within the scope of both functions.

Comment: Ya I made it global. But my bad, i have invoked a non existing method while debugging the main issue. Corrected it now. Thanks for help. Code is working just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `canvas = $('#can')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

This is because any jQuery selectors will return a jQuery object not a JS element instance. If the selector returns only 1 element, it is always in the `0` index of the returned object:

```
canvas = $('#can')[0];
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```